# how to group category levels from references

Tags: mysql, prestashop

Hello i am stuck with this query (is not working).

```
SELECT 
ps_product.reference,cat1,cat2,cat3
FROM ps_category 
    LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang ON ps_category_lang.id_category = ps_category.id_category 
    LEFT JOIN ps_category_product ON ps_category.id_category = ps_category_product.id_category 
    LEFT JOIN ps_product ON ps_product.id_product = ps_category_product.id_product 
WHERE 
(ps_category.nivel = 1 ) cat1,
(ps_category.nivel = 2 ) cat2,
(ps_category.nivel = 3 ) cat3
and 
and ps_category.active = 1 and ps_product.active = 1
```

I wanna the following result, display in rows with fields:
ps_product.reference >> ps_category_lang.name (where in ps_category.nivel = 1) as cat1 >> ps_category_lang.name (where in ps_category.nivel = 2) as cat2 >> ps_category_lang.name (where in ps_category.nivel = 3) as cat3

```
CREATE TABLE `ps_product` (
  `id_product` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_category_default` int(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `reference` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `ps_product` (`id_product`, `id_category_default`,  `reference`, `active`) VALUES
(1, 30, 'PROD1', 1),
(2, 31, 'PROD2', 1),
(3, 32, 'PROD3', 1),
(4, 33, 'PROD4', 1),
(5, 34, 'PROD5', 1),
(6, 35, 'PROD6', 1),
(7, 36, 'PROD7', 1),
(8, 37, 'PROD8', 1),
(9, 38, 'PROD9', 1),
(10, 39, 'PROD10', 1);

CREATE TABLE `ps_category_lang` (
  `id_category` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


INSERT INTO `ps_category_lang` (`id_category`, `name`) VALUES
(1,'Root'),
(10,'MainCat1'),
(11,'MainCat2'),
(12,'MainCat3'),
(13,'MainCat4'),
(14,'MainCat5'),
(15,'MainCat6'),
(16,'ChildMainCat1'),
(17,'ChildMainCat2'),
(18,'ChildMainCat3'),
(19,'ChildMainCat4'),
(20,'ChildMainCat5'),
(21,'ChildMainCat6'),
(22,'ChildMainCat6'),
(23,'ChildMainCat3'),
(24,'ChildMainCat3'),
(25,'ChildMainCat3'),
(26,'ChildMainCat2'),
(27,'ChildMainCat4'),
(28,'ChildMainCat5'),
(29,'ChildMainCat5'),
(30,'OtherChildMainCat1'),
(31,'OtherChildMainCat2'),
(32,'OtherChildMainCat3'),
(33,'OtherChildMainCat4'),
(34,'OtherChildMainCat5'),
(35,'OtherChildMainCat6'),
(36,'OtherChildMainCat6'),
(37,'OtherChildMainCat3'),
(38,'OtherChildMainCat3'),
(39,'OtherChildMainCat3');

CREATE TABLE `ps_category_product` (
  `id_category` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_product` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `ps_category_product` (`id_category`, `id_product`) VALUES
(1,10),
(1,16),
(1,30),
(2,11),
(2,17),
(2,31),
(3,12),
(3,18),
(3,32),
(4,13),
(4,27),
(5,12),
(5,25),
(5,39);

CREATE TABLE `ps_category` (
  `id_category` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `id_parent` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `nivel` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;



INSERT INTO `ps_category` (`id_category`, `id_parent`, `active`, `nivel`) VALUES
(1,0,1,0),
(10,1,1,1),
(11,1,1,1),
(12,1,1,1),
(13,1,1,1),
(14,1,1,1),
(15,1,1,1),
(16,10,1,2),
(17,11,1,2),
(18,12,1,2),
(19,13,1,2),
(20,14,1,2),
(21,15,1,2),
(22,15,1,2),
(23,12,1,2),
(24,12,1,2),
(25,12,1,2),
(26,11,1,2),
(27,13,1,2),
(28,14,1,2),
(29,14,1,2),
(30,16,1,3),
(31,17,1,3),
(32,18,1,3),
(33,19,1,3),
(34,20,1,3),
(35,21,1,3),
(36,22,1,3),
(37,23,1,3),
(38,24,1,3),
(39,25,1,3);
```

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE for all tables, some sample data as INSERT INTO, desired output for this data strictly, and precise MySQL version info. Unnesessary columns may be skipped.

Comment: @Akina thanks for the input i've edited my question with create and insert, thanks for all the help you can give.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to want some sort of pivot query.  Try this version:

```r
SELECT
    psc.reference,
    MAX(CASE WHEN psc.nivel = 1 THEN some_column END) AS cat1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN psc.nivel = 2 THEN some_column END) AS cat2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN psc.nivel = 3 THEN some_column END) AS cat3
FROM ps_category psc
LEFT JOIN ps_category_lang pscl
    ON pscl.id_category = psc.id_category 
LEFT JOIN ps_category_product pscp
    ON psc.id_category = pscp.id_category 
LEFT JOIN ps_product psp
    ON psp.id_product = pscp.id_product 
WHERE
    psc.nivel IN (1, 2, 3) AND
    psc.active = 1 AND
    psp.active = 1
GROUP BY
    psc.reference;
```

Note that you will need to replace `some_column` with the alias/column containing the actual data for the categories.  Your original question, as posted, did not contain this information.

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen but for me doesn't work, maybe is my mistake with question...
I have 4 tables to join.
ps_category (fields are id_category and nivel)
ps_category_lange (fields are id_category and name)
ps_product (fields are id_product and reference)
ps_category_product (fields are id_category and id_product)
So for result i need ps_product.reference, ps_category_lang.name as cat1, ps_product.reference, ps_category_lang.name as cat2, ps_product.reference, ps_category_lang.name as cat3

Comment: Thanks @Tim Biegeleisen i've edited the question because i think is not clear.